# Does `tf.data.Dataset.repeat()` buffer the entire dataset in memory?

Tags: tensorflow

Looking at this code example from the TF documentation:

```py
filenames = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(...)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)
dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
```

Does the `dataset.repeat(num_epochs)` require that the entire dataset be loaded into memory? Or is it re-initializing the dataset(s) that came before it when it receives an end-of-dataset exception?

The documentation is ambiguous about this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this simple test it appears that `repeat` does *not* buffer the dataset, it must be re-initializing the upstream datasets.

```py
n = tf.data.Dataset.range(5).shuffle(buffer_size=5).repeat(2).make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
[sess.run(n) for _ in range(10)]
Out[83]: [2, 0, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4]
```

Logic suggests that if `repeat` were buffering its input, the same random shuffle pattern would have have been repeated in this simple experiment.